# Hyperbolic tangent expansion in temperature

Tags: taylor-expansion, improper-integrals, distribution-theory, hyperbolic-functions

I'm struggling with the following type of integral

$$
\int \limits_0^\infty \mathrm{d} x \, f(x) \tanh \frac{x}{T}
$$

I'm desperately trying to somehow "expand" the hyperbolic tangent for low temperatures, $T > 0$. It's obvious that the first term of this "expansion" should be 1, as in the limit $T \to 0^+$
$$
\lim_{T \to 0^+} \tanh \frac{x}{T} = \text{sign} \, x
$$

The second term is, I think, proportional to delta function, i.e.
$$
\lim_{T \to 0^+} \frac{\partial}{\partial T} \tanh \frac{x}{T} = - \log 2 \, \delta (x)
$$

So in the low-temp expansion the following could be true
$$
\int \limits_0^\infty \mathrm{d} x \, f(x) \tanh \frac{x}{T} = \int \limits_0^\infty f(x) \mathrm{d} x - T \log 2 f (0)
$$

**Is that correct? Does it even make sense what I'm trying to do here? If yes, what would be the "higher terms"? How can we derive them?** Thank you.

You can assume that the function f(x) is "well-behaved", i.e. it goes to zero with $x \to \infty$ so that the integral exists, no singularities etc. I am aware that the $\tanh x/T$ function is not analytic at $T = 0$, but I'm hoping there's some expansion in $T$ if it's under integral with some well-behaved function.

**Example:**

I tried it with $f (x) = e^{-x}$ (the only function Mathematica knows how to integrate with $\tanh$ I guess) and according to Mathematica, the expansion goes like this
$$
\int \limits_0^\infty \mathrm{d} x \, e^{-x} \tanh \frac{x}{T} = 1 + \frac{1}{2} \left( \gamma + \psi (1/2) \right) T + \frac{\pi^2}{24} T^2
$$
(the $T$-term is numerically negative as it should really be)

Every odd term contains some weird polygamma functions and Euler gamma constants, but even terms are nice - powers of $\pi$ divided by some combinatorial stuff. Is this somehow hinting us on the solution?

**EDIT**

In fact, $\psi (1/2) = - \gamma -2 \log 2$, so the second term **really is** -2 \log 2 T, which is in this case $- 2 \log 2 f (0) T$, so I was correct about that Dirac delta term. I am not sure if this is true for any $f(x)$ though.

**EDIT2**

I've stumbled across a function for which this approach fails
$$
f(x) = \frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}}
$$

It is clear that $f^\prime (0)$ and any other derivative in $x = 0$ does not exist (they're infinite). However, as can be found in Mathematica, expansion for the integral in fact *exists* and is equal to
$$
\int \limits_0^\infty \mathrm{d} x \, f(x) \tanh \frac{x}{T} = \sqrt{\pi} - \sqrt{\pi} (2 - \sqrt{2}) \left( - \zeta (1/2) \right) \sqrt{T} + \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4} (\sqrt{2} - 1) \zeta (3/2) T^{3/2} + \cdots
$$

The function $f (x)$ I need to expand is of the form $f (0) - \text{const.} \sqrt{x}$ for small $x$. Is there any chance to find such expansion in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expand $\tanh$ into series:
$$\tanh \frac x T = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty 2(-1)^k e^{-2kx/T}$$
and integrate the series expansion $f(x) = \sum_\alpha c_\alpha x^\alpha$ termwise:
$$\int_0^\infty f(x) \tanh \frac x T dx - \int_0^\infty f(x) dx \sim \\
\sum_\alpha \sum_{k=1}^\infty 2(-1)^k \int_0^\infty
 c_\alpha x^\alpha e^{-2kx/T} dx = \\
-c_0 T \ln 2 + \sum_{\alpha \neq 0}
 (2^{-2\alpha} - 2^{-\alpha}) \Gamma(1+\alpha) \zeta(1+\alpha)
  c_\alpha T^{1+\alpha}.$$

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured out eventually. But thanks anyway, this seems to be the right approach that yields some results.

Answer (score 0):

Reasonable approximations can be derived from $\tanh(x)\approx\min(1,x)$ over $\mathbb{R}^+$.
If the Laplace transform of $f$ is known, exact forms can be derived from
$$ \left(\mathcal{L}^{-1}\tanh\right)(s) = \delta(s) + 2\sum_{n\geq 1}(-1)^n \delta(s-2n) \tag{1}$$
and the fundamental property of the Laplace transform
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty} f(x) g(x)\,dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(\mathcal{L} f\right)(s)\left(\mathcal{L}^{-1} g\right)(s)\,ds.\tag{2}$$